# columnA like %columnB

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-like

I'm trying to do `select * where column1 = % column2 %`.

this is my query

```
select ticket_cp, id_con, raison_sociale, date, Type, RSP
from en_cours,
     Base_Client 
where Base_Client.Client like '%'+raison_sociale+ '%'
```

The error:

> The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: they said that i can't do the add operator at string

Comment: i want like : CIH = aaaaCIHaaa

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Fix the datatype of whatever is `text`. `text` has been deprecated since 2005 (if not earlier) and was effectively replaced with `varchar(MAX)`. `ALTER` your column to be a `varchar(MAX)` and you won't have the problem. But, do you *really* need 2GB of storage for these string values?

Comment: On a side note: Having to join with `LIKE` suggests a bad data model. If there is a client number or name in `raison_sociale`, then why is it hidden there? Why is it not in a separate column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `cast` the `text` to a `varchar(max)`:

```
select ticket_cp, id_con, raison_sociale, date, Type, RSP 
from en_cours e
inner join base_Client b 
    on  b.Client like '%'+ cast(e.raison_sociale as varchar(max)) + '%'
```

Or, if `b.Client` is a `text` too:

```
    on  cast(b.Client as varchar(max)) 
        like   '%'+ cast(e.raison_sociale as varchar(max)) + '%'
```

Notes (most of which already were commented):

- `text` is deprecated; you want to use `nvarchar(max)` (or `nvarchar(max)`) instead
- always use explicit, standard joins (with the `on` keyword) instead of implicit, old-school joins (with commas in the `from` clause)
- columns in the `select` clause should be qualified with the alias of the table they belong to in order to avoid any ambiguity

Comment: the values has been repeated

Answer (score 0):

you could also do a search and replace....

```
SELECT ?.ticket_cp, ?.id_con, a.raison_sociale, ?.date, ?.Type, ?.RSP
FROM en_cours a
INNER JOIN Base_Client b
 ON b.Client LIKE '%', a.raison_sociale '%'
```

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server have `+` as well for concatenation?

Comment: the error 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @@PØlirânté Ñêllÿ....I have edited my answer ..U can check out...

Comment: @AkhileshSingh still not working :/   Incorrect syntax near '%'

Comment: @PØlirânté Ñêllÿ: `CONCAT` has been introduced SQL 2012. `CONCAT` implicitly converts its values to `VARCHAR`, which is what you need. In older versions you can still convert explicitly like shown in GMB's answer. Anyway, rather than trying to find a query that somehow deals with the flawed data model, you may want to fix the data model instead. Akhilesh Singh's last edit makes no sense, by the way; the query is now invalid.

Comment: i'm trying this   select  ticket_cp,id_con , raison_sociale , date, Type,RSP from en_cours , Base_Client where  (Base_Client.Client = CONVERT(varchar(100),raison_sociale) or Base_Client.Client = CONVERT(varchar(100),site_client) or Base_Client.Client = CONVERT(varchar(100),id_con))      it's working for me but there is som repeated row , is there any way to unselect the repeated row ?